# Cheese: No device found

Tags: drivers, camera

I am trying to connect and use a logitech camera in linux on a zedboard (4.9.0-xilinx-00034-g6629200-dirty). I have it connected to the USB OTG port and the kernel image is built from the [xilinx kernel](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx) but with a few modifications.

I have installed cheese and I can see the connected device through lsusb

```
xilinx@pynq:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0824 Logitech, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and inside /dev/ there is no video0 etc. Am I missing any required drivers to make it work?

```
xilinx@pynq:~$ cheese

** (cheese:2105): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-feZvpdUh2v: Connection refused
** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found

...
```

Comment: Are you in the video group? If not, add yourself, logout/login, and voila.

Comment: @schaiba I have added myself to the video group and rebooted, like you suggested. However, I'm still getting the same error.